# For loop on 2 lists and add to an object

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, loops, arraylist

Im looping over two lists and want to add the objects to a custom object. So Im getting an `Employee` a list of `Projects` and a list of `Doubles` from Thymeleaf and save them to a database. I want to save them to the object `EmployeeProject` which takes an Employee, a Project and a double (employeeBookedMonths). My problem is I either get the multiple projects saved to the EmployeeProject but all the project months are the same (the last double value one in the list) or I save the multiple projects to the employeeProject with correct employeeBookedMonths but there is dupicates, for example if I save 3 projects with 3 employeeBookedMonths, I get 3 times each saved (so 9 saved). I've tried moving the `employeeProjectService.saveEmployeeProject` but can't make it work plus many other variations but I need some help.

Question: how can I loop through the 2 lists and add and them to the EmployeeProject object? Without getting multiples or only getting the last employeeBookedMonths.

Thanks in advance.

Also the `System.println` prints the wanted values, they just don't save.

```
    public String saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee,
                               @RequestParam("projectId") List<Project> projectIds,
                               @RequestParam("employeeProjectMonths") List<Double> months) {
        List<Double> monthList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Double month : months) {
            if (month != null) {
                monthList.add(month);
                System.out.println("Month:" + month);
            }
        }
        employeeService.saveEmployee(employee);
        if (projectIds != null) {
            EmployeeProject employeeProject = new EmployeeProject(employee);
            for (Project ids : projectIds) {
                for (Double month : monthList) {
                    employeeProject.setEmployeeBookedMonths(month);
                    System.out.println("Months: " + employeeProject.getEmployeeBookedMonths());
                    employeeProjectService.saveEmployeeProject(employee, ids, month);
                }
            }
        }
        return "redirect:/ines/employees";
    }
```

New Employee form

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/ines/saveEmployeeMeeting}" th:object="${employee}"
            method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email:</label>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"
                       placeholder="Employee Name" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">
            </div>
            <th:block th:object="${meetingInfo}">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Start Time:</label>
                    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input"
                               th:field="*{meetingStartDateTime}" id="meetingStartDateTime"/>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>End Time:</label>
                    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2" data-target-input="nearest">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1"
                               th:field="*{meetingEndDateTime}" id="meetingEndDateTime" placeholder="Date"/>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" th:field="*{message}"
                       placeholder="Message" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">
            </div>
            </th:block>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info col-2">Save Employee/Meeting</button>
        </form>
```

Employee

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    @Column(name = "contracted_from")
    private String contractedFrom;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    @Column(name = "contracted_to")
    private String contractedTo;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL
//          fetch=FetchType.EAGER
    )
    private Set<EmployeeProject> employeeProjects = new HashSet<>();
// constructores getters and setters
```

Project

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
public class Project implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "project_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private Long projectNumber;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String name;


    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    @Column(name = "start_date", nullable = false)
    private String startDate;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    @Column(name = "end_date", nullable = false)
    private String endDate;

    @Column(name = "project_length_months")
    private double projectLengthInMonths;

    @Column(name = "project_booked_months")
    private double currentBookedMonths;

    @Column(name = "remaining_booked_months")
    private double remainingBookedMonths;

    private int numberOfEmployees;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<EmployeeProject> employeeProjects = new HashSet<>();
// constructores getters and setters
```

EmployeeProject

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_projects")
public class EmployeeProject implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "employee_project_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
    private Employee employee;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    private Project project;

    @Column(name = "employee_booked_months")
    private double employeeBookedMonths;
// constructores getters and setters
```

Comment: 1. the description is too long and meandering. please edit the question and specify expected result. 2, post should contain only one question

Comment: My apologies but I've seen much longer descriptions on here, I've added a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not the prettiest but it works, I feel a bit dumb after this one but if anyone has a more elegant approach I'm happy to see it.

```
@PostMapping("/saveEmployee")
    public String saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee,
                               @RequestParam("projectId") List<Project> projectIds,
                               @RequestParam("employeeProjectMonths") List<Double> months) {

        List<Double> monthList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Double month : months) {
            if (month != null) {
                monthList.add(month);
                System.out.println("Month:" + month);
            }
        }

        List<Project> projectList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Project project : projectIds) {
            if (project != null) {
                projectList.add(project);
                System.out.println("Project:" + project);
            }
        }

        employeeService.saveEmployee(employee);
        for (int i=0; i<= monthList.size(); i++) {
            EmployeeProject employeeProject = new EmployeeProject(employee);
            employeeProject.setEmployeeBookedMonths(monthList.get(i));
            employeeProject.setProject(new Project(projectList.get(i).getId()));
            employeeProjectService.saveEmployeeProjectEmployeeOnly(employeeProject);
        }
        return "redirect:/ines/employees";
    }
```

The problem was I was getting the list of projectIds which also had the null values (not selected ones), so I had to create a list of the projects then use the i loop to set each Project and employeeProjectMonths.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
employeeProjectService.saveEmployeeProject(employee, ids, month);
```

it was supposed to save `employee` or `employeeProject`?
Because in the code you didn't use the variable `employeeProject` explicitly. Where it was supposed to be saved?

Comment: In that line I save an EmployeeProejct, so before the loop I save a new Employee, then there is existing Project (with a checkbox) and next to the checkbox is a textfield to add employeeBookedMonths. So I thought if there is a list of months and a list of projects I could loop through and add them to the EmployeeProject. I've added the html if that helps. I open to a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider that you're declaring  `EmployeeProject employeeProject = new EmployeeProject(employee);` inside   `if (projectIds != null) {` scope, so if you do println in the `employeeProject`, right above `return "redirect:/ines/employees";` (outside the scope) you won't see it? In order to don't loose the data you need to declare `employeeProject` at the beginning of the method.

The follow code could correct this:

```java
    public String saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee,
                               @RequestParam("projectId") List<Project> projectIds,
                               @RequestParam("employeeProjectMonths") List<Double> months) {
        List<EmployeeProject> listOfEmployeeProjects = ArrayList<>();
        List<Double> monthList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Double month : months) {
            if (month != null) {
                monthList.add(month);
                System.out.println("Month:" + month);
            }
        }
        employeeService.saveEmployee(employee);
        if (projectIds != null) {
            EmployeeProject employeeProject = new EmployeeProject(employee);
            for (Project ids : projectIds) {
                for (Double month : monthList) {
                    employeeProject.setEmployeeBookedMonths(month);
                    System.out.println("Months: " + employeeProject.getEmployeeBookedMonths());
                    employeeProjectService.saveEmployeeProject(employee, ids, month);
                }
            }
        listOfEmployeeProjects.add(employeeProject);
        }
    //Here you might see the data inside listOfEmployeeProjects, once it was declared in a outter scope
   //Maybe do a assign of your data to other field, for example: 
   // mainData.setAllOfTheEmployeeProjects(listOfEmployeeProjects);
        return "redirect:/ines/employees";
    }
```

Did it help? If didn't please post the rest of your code.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I added the Employee, Project and EmployeeProject entities. I tried what you said and it just prints out a listOfEmployeeProjects with 3 x EmployeeProjects all the same with the last employeeBooked months entered (in this case) 5.5. Here is one: ```listOfEmployeeProjects[EmployeeProject{id=null, employee=Employee{id=5, name='Test Employee', contractedFrom='2022-11-20', contractedTo='2022-12-10', employeeProjects=[]}, project=null, employeeBookedMonths=5.5}]```

Comment: Maybe it's because you used:  ```private Set<EmployeeProject> employeeProjects = new HashSet<>(); ``` . Try to use just: ```private Set<EmployeeProject> employeeProjects;``` either in classes ```Project``` and ```Employee```. Inside the class ```EmployeeProject```  implement the ```equals()``` and  ```hashCode()``` methods based in all fields of this class - it's necessary in order to java differentiate the EmployeeProject objects.